# ¿Cómo pasar información de un archivo .txt a una estructura?

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos

Digamos que en un archivo .txt tengo la siguiente información:

```
100 Pedro Rodriguez H 10 CASADO 0 150
```

Y en [c](/questions/tagged/c) quiero leer esa información y guardarlos en una estructura como esta:

```
struct empleados {
  int ID;
  char nombre[50];
  char apellidos[50];
  char sexo;
  int edadExperienca;
  char estadoCivil[30];
  int nHijos;
  int horasTrabajadas;
}
arrayEmpleados[100];
```

¿Cómo le haría para guardar la información en su debido campo?
No tengo una idea muy clara de lo que debería hacer.

Comment: No estoy seguro de marcarla como duplicada, pero hay **varias** sobre el mismo tema: https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5Dleer. Seguro que una o varias te sirve.

Comment: Tu pregunta es muy amplia, cual es realmente tu problema, ¿leer el archivo?¿separar el contenido para guardarlo en la estructura?¿guardar la información ya separada en la estructura?

Comment: Mil disculpas, el problema aquí es como separaría cada elemento para guardarla en la estructura, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Por favor, muestranos el código que tienes hecho hasta ahora y detalla el error que te produce: mensajes del compilador, comportamiento esperado/obtenido ... [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/67224/19610) tu pregunta con los detalles exactos. Si no sabes como empezar, alguna de las preguntas/respuestas del enlace que te di antes deberían de orientarte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De con `strtok` puedes separar tu `string`, en este ejemplo guardo los datos en un array, y luego acceso a ellos por indice para asignarlo a un atributo de la estructura `strcpy( empleado.nombre, a[1]);`

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char string[] = "100 Pedro Rodriguez H 10 CASADO 0 150";
char separador[]   = " ";
char a[8][50];
int i;
char *palabra;

struct empleados{
int ID;
char nombre[50];
char apellidos[50];
char sexo;
int edadExperienca;
char estadoCivil[30];
int nHijos;
int horasTrabajadas;
};

int main( void )
{
   struct empleados empleado;
   i=0;
   palabra = strtok( string, separador );
   while( palabra != NULL )
   {
      strcpy(a[i], palabra);
      i++;
      printf( " %s\n", palabra );
      palabra = strtok( NULL, separador );
   }
   strcpy( empleado.nombre, a[1]);
   printf( " %s\n", empleado.nombre );
}
```